# Bash lstlistings treats "$#" as a comment

Tags: listings, parsing

**Background:** In Bash, `$#` represents the number of arguments, and `#` starts a comment.

Consider the following Bash script:

```bash
# This is a comment
while [[ $# -gt 0 ]]; do
    echo $1
    shift
done
```

Note that the syntax coloring by StackExchange here is *incorrect*! The `#` in `$#` is being treated as a comment marker.

Unfortunately, the `listings` package gives me the same result:

[image: Example of incorrect syntax parsing]
     
[image: The same example with a different style]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{language=Bash}

\pagenumbering{gobble}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}
# This is a comment
while [[ $# -gt 0 ]]; do
    echo $1
    shift
done
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

How can I fix this and get `listings` to display the right output?

Comment: Not sure if it's quite what you want, but `\lstset{language = bash, otherkeywords = $\#}` will make `$#` a keyword and so not start a comment.

Comment: @JosephWright Ooh, that's very close. It does treat it as a keyword, not a variable (of course), but I'd be willing to make that compromise.

Comment: @JosephWright arg I tried that with `morekeywords` and it didn't work:-) if `otherkeywords` works I should delete my answer:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I don't think it's perfect (as noted, it ends up as a keyword not a variable, which is why it's a comment not an answer).

Comment: `$#` should not be a special case. The # character does not introduce a comment if it is immediately preceded by *any* non-whitespace character or is enclosed in single or double quotes. `#this is a comment echo this# is not a comment echo neither is#this for that matter. echo not a comment #but this is X=this is not "a # comment either"`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Whoever wrote the `listings` language for `bash` probably didn't anticipate this case. Actually, the `listings` package is a far cry from a proper lexical analyser and doesn't offer a clean way of doing this kind of syntax highlighting. As far as `listings`' `Bash` language is concerned, a `#` character encountered in normal "processing" mode starts a comment, and that is it.

An easy, if ugly, fix is to use the `literate` key to replace all instances of the `$#` pattern by... well... itself... in order to prevent the `#` character from starting a comment if preceded by `$`:

[image]

Unfortunately, this trick has side effects: if `columns=fullflexible` is used, space characters following `$#` (if any) get gobbled, which is undesirable.
One way to fix this is to use the `keepspaces` option, also.

Update: Actually, the workaround for preventing spaces from getting gobbled that Manuel mentions in [his answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/209641/21891) is preferable to setting `keepspaces`; have a look.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}

\lstset{
  language = Bash,
  literate = {\$\#}{{{\$\#}}}2,
  columns  = fullflexible,
  keepspaces,
}

\pagenumbering{gobble}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}
# This is a comment
while [[ $# -gt 0 ]]; do
    echo $1
    shift
done
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This is nice, but it loses the space after `$#` with `columns=fullflexible`.

Comment: @WChargin Not if you also use the `keepspaces` option.

Comment: What about `literate = {\$\#}{{{\$\#}}}2 {\$\# }{{{\$\# }}}2`?

Comment: @Manuel Your approach works fine if only one space character follows, but if you have more after that, those will get gobbled.

Comment: @Jubobs But that happens if you don't use `keepspaces`. By the way, the problem is that, even in the default `columns` it seems that there's a space, but there isn't, it's like a “part of the glyph”.

Comment: @Manuel I see what you mean now. Your approach is indeed preferable.

Comment: Can you explain why the second argument (?) to literate requires to be embedded in three sets of braces?

Answer (score 5):

If you don't mind adding markup to the listing you can define an `escapechar` and hide the `#`

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{language=Bash,escapechar=^}

\pagenumbering{gobble}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}
# This is a comment
while [[ $^\#^ -gt 0 ]]; do
    echo $1
    shift
done
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}

\lstset
 {
  language = Bash,
  literate = {\$\#}{{{\$\#}}}2 {\$\# }{{{\$\# }}}2,
  columns  = fullflexible,
 }

\pagenumbering{gobble}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}
# This is a comment
while [[ $# -gt 0 ]]; do
    echo $1
    shift
done
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I think I see what you meant earlier...

Comment: :) I tend not to explain myself quite good (I'm not that good at English). The thing is that, unles `keepspaces` is triggered, many spaces are converted to just one (at least in this example), so they are not “gobbled”. I meant that this (half-)solution is independent of `keepspaces`.

Answer (score 2):

I can suggest using `pythontex`. A run of the program `pythontex` is needed when the listings change. The example uses `beramono` so boldface is distinguishable in the monospaced font.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{beramono}

\usepackage[pygopt={style=bw}]{pythontex}

\begin{document}

\begin{pygments}{bash}
# This is a comment
while [[ $# -gt 0 ]]; do
    echo $1
    shift
done
\end{pygments}

\end{document}
```

[image]