# Using Bash listings to bold variables and functions

Tags: listings

I am using the `listings` package to show some sample bash script lines; however, the `otherkeywords` argument is giving me trouble. As the `listings` documentation states:

> If one keyword is a subsequence of another (like -- and -->), you must specify the shorter first.

But this does not seem to be borne out in practice, at least not with curly brace characters. I'll admit I'm hoping this is simply some escape syntax mistake.

```
\documentclass[preview,varwidth,border=5pt]{standalone}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{
  beramono,
  listings,
  textcomp
}

\lstset{breaklines=true,
frame=tb,
language=bash,
breakatwhitespace=true,
alsoletter={*()"'0123456789.},
alsoother={\{\=\}},
basicstyle={\small\ttfamily},
commentstyle={\itshape},
keywordstyle={\bfseries},
literate={{=}{{{=}}}1},
prebreak={\textbackslash},
sensitive=true,
stepnumber=1,
tabsize=4,
upquote=true,
morekeywords={echo, function},
otherkeywords={},
otherkeywords={
  -, \{, $\{, \}
}}
%% Removing the left curly-brace from the list of otherkeywords make variable names look right but not function clauses.
%% (The hyphen is needed only because the otherkeywords list cannot start with an escaped curly brace.)

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}
function test() { VAR='$12'; echo ${VAR}; }
\end{lstlisting}

Should look like:

\texttt{{\bfseries{}function} test() {\bfseries{}\{} VAR='\$12'; {\bfseries{}\$\{}VAR{\bfseries{}\}}; {\bfseries{}\}}}

but all of the following are wrong:

\texttt{{\bfseries{}function} test() {\bfseries{}\{} VAR='\$12'; \${\bfseries{}\{}VAR{\bfseries{}\}}; {\bfseries{}\}}}

\texttt{{\bfseries{}function} test() \{ VAR='\$12'; {\bfseries{}\$\{}VAR{\bfseries{}\}}; {\bfseries{}\}}}

\texttt{{\bfseries{}function} test() {\bfseries{}\{} VAR='{\bfseries{}\$}12'; {\bfseries{}\$\{}VAR{\bfseries{}\}}; {\bfseries{}\}}}

\end{document}
```

**Result:** (notice which characters are in bold)
[image: curly braces in bash script in listing]

In short, placing the `\{` keyword first does not allow the `$\{` keyword to also be recognized. Moving `\{` in the list order makes no difference, whereas removing it allows `$\{` to be recognized, but *not* a single `{` character. I've also tried escaping the `$` character to no effect.

Please note that this does not seem to be exactly a duplicate of e.g. [R listings operator partially in bold](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/62518/r-listings-operator-partially-in-bold) because placing the short version first, as the accepted answer/workaround there points out, does not solve my case.

Comment: No sooner did I post this than I read (http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/209632/bash-lstlistings-treats-as-a-comment) which gave me of course the idea to just add `literate={\$\{}{{{{\bfseries{}\$\{}}}}2,` and remove `$\{` from `otherkeywords` entirely. Good enough workaround for me.

Comment: So post your own answer as an answer instead of a comment.

Comment: Good point @AFeldman. Done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reading [Bash lstlistings treats “$#” as a comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/209632/bash-lstlistings-treats-as-a-comment) gave me the idea to just add a `literate` to solve this case. In my listings settings, I added `literate={\$\{}{{{{\bfseries{}\$\{}}}}2,` and removed `$\{` from the `otherkeywords` list entirely. In point of fact, unlike my MWE, since I am using LyX, I solved it by adding it to an `\AtBeginDocument{}` in my LaTeX Preamble, e.g.:

```
\documentclass[varwidth,border=5pt]{standalone}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{
  color,
  beramono,
  listings,
  textcomp
}

\definecolor{lightgray}{RGB}{245,245,245}
\definecolor{darkgray}{RGB}{128,128,128}

\lstset{
  abovecaptionskip={0cm},
  backgroundcolor={\color{lightgray}},
  basicstyle={\small\ttfamily},
  breakatwhitespace=true,
  breaklines=true,
  captionpos=b,
  frame=tb,
  resetmargins=true,
  sensitive=true,
  stepnumber=1,
  tabsize=4,
  upquote=true
}

\AtBeginDocument{\lstdefinelanguage{bash}[]{sh}%
  {morekeywords={alias,bg,bind,builtin,caller,command,compgen,compopt,%
      complete,coproc,curl,declare,disown,dirs,enable,fc,fg,help,%
      history,jobs,let,local,logout,mapfile,printf,pushd,popd,%
      readarray,select,set,suspend,shopt,source,times,type,typeset,%
      ulimit,unalias,wait},%
   otherkeywords={ [, ], [[, ]], \{, \} }%
  }%

\lstdefinelanguage{sh}%
  {morekeywords={awk,break,case,cat,cd,continue,do,done,echo,elif,else,%
      env,esac,eval,exec,exit,export,expr,false,fi,for,function,getopts,%
      hash,history,if,in,kill,login,newgrp,nice,nohup,ps,pwd,read,%
      readonly,return,set,sed,shift,test,then,times,trap,true,type,%
      ulimit,umask,unset,until,wait,while},%
   morecomment=[l]\#,%
   morestring=[d]",%
   alsoletter={*"'0123456789.},%
   alsoother={\{\=\}},%
   literate={{=}{{{=}}}1},%
   literate={\$\{}{{{{\bfseries{}\$\{}}}}2,%
   otherkeywords={ [, ], \{, \} }%
  }[keywords,comments,strings]%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[language=bash]
function test() { VAR='$12'; echo ${VAR}; }
for i in "one" "two" "three" "four" "five"; do
  printf "%7s\n" "${i}"
done
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

So, perhaps redefining my `bash` and `sh` listing language definitions is overkill, but this specific way, I get to keep it in the document rather than editing my `lstlangX.sty` files directly *and* it won't collide with other languages you might also list in the same document, like Python. It's less than pretty, but you don't get the so-called ERT in LyX, for what it's worth.

**Result:**
[image: New sort-of LyX-friendly result]

(This is a more specific answer than the one in my original question; not so much a mere correction of the MWE, but this was my specific case, so the above is closer to my specific solution.)